# Android emulator After Wiping Data on Virtual devices unable to connect to 10.0.2.2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost

I am using Android emulator for testing. One test contains cookie related mechanism, and to reset (retest) I need to remove existing cookie. I figured I will 'Wipe device' and that should eliminate any cookies and other stuff.

After wipe when trying to navigate to my local machine (http://10.0.2.2:50766/)  I started getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I am running IISExpress running on Visual Studio. I haven't changed anything between wipe didn't even stop debugging session, which is very odd.

**Has anyone experienced something similar and knows how to solve it.**

**UPDATE**

I just realized it only works once -> when device first boots and browser is opened -> It goes to google and works ok, can do search and get results. Then when I try to go to 10.0.2.2 it fails, but after it had failed if I try to go back to google on same url it fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
I would loose internet only when I hit 10.0.2.2 not just any other site (like yahoo)

Turns out I messed up port while typing manually (50667) instead of (50766). My guess is antivirus would block it for trying to call on something that does not exist because it looks like something is trying to scan ports.

[image]